# Too many sleeping processes (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, devops

I have an issue in the peak hours where I get "error establishing a database connection”. In the logs, it’s “Too many connections”. I can’t connect to the DB manually without restarting mysql first.

I checked what is happening in the DB and it looks like that it’s mostly sleeping processes. I have no idea why.

On the server I run 10+ Wordpress sites with various themes&plugins (all through https://spinupwp.com/). What I did now is I ran [MySQLTuner-perl](https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl) and implemented its recommendations as MySQL was in the default settings. And I'm waiting for the peak hours which is not the smartest I think.

**Can you recommend me a way how to identify which PHP file or http request is responsible for this?**

```
mysql> show processlist;
+-------+-------+-----------+-----------------------+---------+------+----------+------------------+
| Id    | User  | Host      | db                    | Command | Time | State    | Info             |
+-------+-------+-----------+-----------------------+---------+------+----------+------------------+
|   423 | dbuser | localhost | NULL                  | Query   |    0 | starting | show processlist |
|   448 | dbuser | localhost | my_dbname_wp | Sleep   |  242 |          | NULL             |
|   452 | dbuser | localhost | my_dbname_wp | Sleep   |  242 |          | NULL             |
|   455 | dbuser | localhost | my_dbname_wp | Sleep   |  241 |          | NULL             |
|   936 | dbuser | localhost | my_dbname_wp | Sleep   |  217 |          | NULL             |
|  5715 | dbuser | localhost | my_dbname_wp | Sleep   |  164 |          | NULL             |
|  8669 | dbuser | localhost | my_dbname_wp | Sleep   |  139 |          | NULL             |
| 10353 | dbuser | localhost | my_dbname_wp | Sleep   |  125 |          | NULL             |
| 10631 | dbuser | localhost | my_dbname_wp | Sleep   |  123 |          | NULL             |
| 10724 | dbuser | localhost | my_dbname_wp | Sleep   |  122 |          | NULL             |
| 10867 | dbuser | localhost | my_dbname_wp | Sleep   |  121 |          | NULL             |
| 11084 | dbuser | localhost | my_dbname_wp | Sleep   |  119 |          | NULL             |
| 11102 | dbuser | localhost | my_dbname_wp | Sleep   |  119 |          | NULL             |
| 11226 | dbuser | localhost | my_dbname_wp | Sleep   |  118 |          | NULL             |
| 11669 | dbuser | localhost | my_dbname_wp | Sleep   |  114 |          | NULL             |
| 11726 | dbuser | localhost | my_dbname_wp | Sleep   |  114 |          | NULL             |
| 11851 | dbuser | localhost | my_dbname_wp | Sleep   |  113 |          | NULL             |
| 11994 | dbuser | localhost | my_dbname_wp | Sleep   |  112 |          | NULL             |
| 12006 | dbuser | localhost | my_dbname_wp | Sleep   |  112 |          | NULL
```

Comment: Please post a new 'SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;' for comparison to your original.

Comment: SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; will include the QUERY running.  And post the entire output, not just the first page.  You may have to post to pastebin.com and share the link, please.  Also post your PHP code that is used to CONNECT, PROCESS, DISCONNECT.  It looks like someone forgot to 'CLOSE' the connection.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was this plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-json-api/. It was blocking some /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php requests which were left hanging out. Disabling the plugin is not a proper solution, but it helped.